# How do I get the return value of the EXISTS operator with QtSql?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5

The EXISTS operator always evaluates to one of the integer values 0 and 1. I tried to get them via [QSqlQuery::value(int index)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#value). But somehow this result is not related to a column. How do I get the return value of the EXISTS operator with QtSql?

```
query.prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM files WHERE pid=:pid AND files.name=':name' LIMIT 1);");
query.bindValue(":pid", PID);
query.bindValue(":name", fi.fileName());
if (!query.exec()){
    qCritical() << query.lastError();
    qFatal(SQLERR);
}
```

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: Q: Why not `SELECT mycol FROM mytable`?  If you get an error, the column doesn't exist.  Or even better, query the schema: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

Comment: Because error handlers exist to catch errors not expected values.

Comment: Which DB plugin do you use ?

Comment: `db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");`

Comment: Q: are you trying to check of the *column* exists ... or if a row matching your WHERE exists ... or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query.prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM files WHERE pid=:pid AND files.name=':name' LIMIT 1);");
query.bindValue(":pid", PID);
query.bindValue(":name", fi.fileName());
if (!query.exec()){
    qCritical() << query.lastError();
    qFatal(SQLERR);
}
else
{
    if( query.next( ) )
        QMessageBox::information( NULL , "Test" , query.value( 0 ).toString( ) );
}
```

That works perfectly for me.
Basically `.next( )` will retrieve the next possible query result and then you can access it using `query.value( 0 )` if the value exists in my query I get `1` returned and when it doesn't I get `0`

Comment: Okay time to go to bed. I definitively read this, but forgot it: Successfully executed SQL statements set the query's state to active so that isActive() returns true. Otherwise the query's state is set to inactive. In either case, when executing a new SQL statement, the query is positioned on an invalid record. An active query must be navigated to a valid record (so that isValid() returns true) before values can be retrieved. (From the docs)